# Is this statement true? "For every positive number $x$, there exists a positive number $y$ such that $y<x$"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Maybe this will sound funny but I'm genuinely having problem in this example.

My book says that the statement

> $p:$ For every positive number $x$, there exists a positive number $y$ such that $y<x$.

is true.

---

How can this statement be true$?$ Suppose we take $x=1$. Then there is no $y\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ that is $<x$

Am I wrong$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Edit

The above problem is solved now. Consider another statement

> $q:$ There exists a positive number $y$ such that for every positive number $x$, we have $y<x$.

My book says that $q$ is false. How$?$ If $p$ was true then how  can $q$ be false$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably they mean positive *real* number

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks...i dunno why I thought that the domain is integers but I've another doubt can you pls help me solve that?$?

Comment: Perhaps they meant the rationals.  In either case (real or rational), taking $\frac x2$ should do the job.

Comment: Post edit:  this is a question of quantifiers.   For the second statement, a single $y$ is meant to work *for all* positive $x$.

Comment: @lulu how to deal with these type of questions

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  In both cases, your confusion appears to arise from not paying attention to details.  So, I suggest focussing on details going forward.  Quantifiers are critical, and it's important to get them straight.

Comment: The second (edited) question says (in English) that there is a number smaller than every positive number. That's false: if $y$ were such a number it would not be smaller than $y/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referring to numbers on the real line, not the integers. You can use the density of the rationals here, or simply choose $N>0$ large enough so that (1) $\frac{1}{N} < p$ for positive $p$. To answer your second question, if we have any fixed positive number $p$ we simply use (1) to find a smaller positive number.

Comment: Please solve my second query